# Undefined reference error linking shared object

Tags: gcc, g++, centos, shared

I have **shared library** which is dependent on a few **static libraries** which includes *zlib* etc. When I am building my shared library with the dependent static libraries with g++ (cent os 6.3) it is getting compiled fine. Now when I try to use my shared library on a test project I am getting a lot of unresolved errors. What I am doing wrong ?

> g++ -L/usr/local/lib -L/home/de.../workspace/libtest/Debug -o "mytest"
> ./src/mytest.o -ltest
>
> /home/de.../workspace/libtest/Debug/libtest.so: undefined reference to `BZ2_bzCompressEnd'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1):

The error makes it look like you need to link against bzip2 as well:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -L/home/de.../workspace/libtest/Debug -o "mytest" ./src/mytest.o -ltest -lbz2
```

You do need to be careful about linking static libraries into a shared one, but you're seeing this error because you need to link in the remaining libraries.

Comment: But the purpose of using the static dependencies will be lost. I have already created a single shared object which includes all the static dependencies. Now all applications would need only one dependent shared object only. Also even after linking *bz2* is not solving the issue.

Comment: You need to make sure the static libraries are compiled with `-fPIC`, and it'll be okay.  You might also need to use something like `-Wl,-Bstatic` to make sure gcc links against the static version of the libraries you've specified.  If you don't, it will choose the shared versions by default.

Comment: You mean I will have to rebuild the static libraries with the -fPIC option or just the shared library ?

Comment: The dependencies of the shared library, and the library itself.  I didn't mean to sidetrack you with that though--I was just warning you about the issue.  You said you were building a shared library for use by your application... where is that library on the command line?  Note that a `.o` is not the same thing as a shared library.  A `.o` doesn't get linked against dependencies.  Somewhere on that command line should be a `-lyour_shared_library`.

Comment: It is there already "-ltest". Also reconfiguring the libraries with -fPIC didn't solve the problem. What do I do now.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that before!  Did you statically link test.so against libbz2?

Comment: Yes test.so is statically linked to libbz. Now when i am linking my application with test.o I am getting lots of undefined errors.

Comment: Without seeing how test.so is being built, it's hard to give you any more advice.  I'd be willing to bet that libbz2 is not being statically linked to test.so though.

Comment: It is now compiling file. I have recompiled all the dependent libraries with the flag CFLAGS='-O2 -fPIC'. No my shared library is compiling fine without complaining. I think the linking order of libraries is also important.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on how you solved this? I'm having an identical issue where I build a .so library from three .a libraries. I compile all three with -fPIC and the shared library builds fine, but when I try to build an example program it fails in the link stage with undefined references to the static libraries.